# Dealing with MySql pooling and nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection-pooling, node-mysql

I run an web server written in NodeJS/ EXPRESS that deals with a MySQL db.
In order to be more efficient, I use the pooling mechanism of node-mysql.

An I still get some issues about :
- connection lost
- cannot release already release connection
- there is no release of undefined

Depending on the request, various code pattern can then be used to get the data and release the connection :

1/ standard callback ...,`function(err, rows){...}`
- I may understood, that the release shall be done before the callback ? Please confirm me !
- May I even use the release at the first line of the call back function ? (because I may have many case in the case with various callback.

2/ with event 
- I put a connection.release in both events `.on('error')` and `.on('end')`. Is that enough ?
- What happen if a error is called on they 10th rows. Does both event will be called ? I think not, but I got some issue (can,not release a already release connection) with the following code :

```
   pool.getConnection(function(err, mysqlConnection) {

        if (err != null) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {

            mysqlConnection.query('USE table');

            var xs = new Array();

            if (selectedB === 'B') {
                if (selectedC === 'C') {

                    var queryCmd = "SELECT DISTINCT nom FROM x WHERE a ='" + selectedA + "'";
                    var query = mysqlConnection.query(queryCmd);

                    query
                    // ERROR
                    .on('error', function(err) {
                        mysqlConnection.release();
                    })
                    // RESULT
                    .on('result', function(row) {
                        mysqlConnection.pause();
                        var x = row['nom'];
                        xs.push(x);
                        mysqlConnection.resume();
                    })
                    // END
                    .on('end', function() {
                        mysqlConnection.release();
                        callback(xs);
                    })

                }
                else {
                    mysqlConnection.release();
                    callback([]);
                }
            }
            else {
                mysqlConnection.release();
                callback([]);
            }
        }

    });
```

3/ with return
- call release before return !

Then, there are some snippets about error handling for standard connection, what should we do for connection pooling ? cause in case, it crash the server !

Thanks in advance for you advises. That will definitively help me a lot !

Comment: I suggest to use knex, it handle all this issues... https://knexjs.org